# Support for hyperlinks merge in Xlsx files

Tags: xlsx, opentbs

We are trying to merge hyperlinks in `xlsx` files, like in this example:

```
[$array.field1;block=row]   [$array.field_hyperilink]
```

In the excel template we put the cell type of `[$array.field_hyperilink]` as hyperlink .

However, the field will get merged as normal text.

Is there anything we can do to get this feature working with opentbs?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks in XLSX are something quite complicated to manage because they are stored apart, not in the cell where they appear.

OpenTBS cannot manage hyperlinks in XLSX for now (version 1.12.0). You can still save hyperlinks as simple text in a cell.